# migrate whole MS ACCESS to MYSQL at one time

Tags: mysql, ms-access

I wand to migrate a msaccess database to mysql.
I know how to do it table by table: (create odbc link, then right click on table and export)

As I have 40 tables, and as I need to migrate this database several times, I would like to automate this migration.
Is there a way (vb script for example) to do that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I used mdbtools but i had to write a custom bash script because you cannot migrate all tables at once with mdbtools.

Comment: Did you even TRY searching a bit ?? http://www.bullzip.com/products/a2m/info.php

Comment: I did try... ;) bullzip creates some problems about the field types. Some values are mis interpreted.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following VBA solution which assumes all 40 corresponding tables are already created in MySQL and that you have a MySQL ODBC driver installed. The procedure essentially links all tables into Access database and runs append queries all in a recordset loop.

First, create an Excel file of the list of MySQL tables which assumes they are the same exact names of Access tables with query:

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE table_name = "table";
```

Then in Access VBA, run the following as a subroutine or function:

```
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim rst As DAO.Recordset

' Import MySQL table list
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12, "MySQLTables", _
      "C:\Path\To\MySQLExcelList.xlsx", True

Set db = currentdb()
Set rst = db.OpenRecordset("MySQLTables", dbOpenDynaset)

rst.MoveLast
rst.MoveFirst

Do While Not rst.EOF
    ' LINK TABLES

    ' ODBC DSN CONNECTION
     DoCmd.TransferDatabase acLink, "ODBC Database", _
      "ODBC;DSN=NameOfDSN;server=servername;database=dbname;" _
       & "UID=username;PWD=password;", acTable, rst![column_name], "mysql_" & rst![column_name]

    ' ODBC DSN-LESS CONNECTION
    'DoCmd.TransferDatabase acLink, "ODBC Database", _
    '  "ODBC;DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 5.3 Unicode Driver};server=servername;database=dbname;" _
    '  & "UID=username;PWD=password;", acTable, rst![column_name], "mysql_" & rst![column_name]


    ' APPENDS DATA
    db.Execute "INSERT INTO mysql_" & rst![column_name] & _
               " SELECT * FROM " & rst![column_name] & ";", dbFailOnError
    rst.MoveNext
Loop

rst.Close

Set rst = Nothing        
Set db = Nothing
```

Comment: the transferdatabase of your code gave me an error : le type de base de donnees odbc database n'est pas installé , so I have tried another one : DoCmd.TransferDatabase acLink, "ODBC Database", _
"ODBC;DSN=myDataSource;UID=root;PWD=root;" _
& "DATABASE=myDb", acTable, "Authors", "dboAuthors"  but I came to the same error. I know my dsn works as I can export one table manually. I don't understand why I am getting this error though.

Comment: Check your C:\Windows\Systems32 (32-bit CPUs) and/or C:\Windows\SysWOW64 (64-bit CPUs) folders, find and open odbcad32.exe which lists all ODBC DSNs and Drivers. See if any MySQL drivers appear.

Comment: The DSN appears. Actually  I am using it when I export one table to Mysql (by right clicking on the table)

Comment: There are two ways to connect via ODBC: by a DSN or by a Driver (DSN-less). My original used Driver method (the generalized version) but I edited my answer to include both options (Driver version commented out); odbcad32.exe lists both. Change according to your needs.

Comment: well, there must be something wrong with my computer or ms access because I am having the same problem using DSN or by a driver

Comment: Do you receive same EXACT error as above (in French)? Does DSN have a space in its name? Is the Driver 5.3 Unicode or ANSI? Adjust to your specifications. Can you screenshot your odbcad32.exe? You might have MySQL Driver installed as 32-bit and MS Access as 64-bit. Notice I gave two C:\Windows folders. Try manually linking ODBC tables under External Data to see if it's possible.